# Get the date of the Saturday after next Sunday

Tags: php, date

I have the following code and everything is working fine except for $the_saturday_after_next_sunday. It is not outputting the correct date. Can you please help me display the date correctly?

Thanks for the help.

```
<?php
$today = date('m/d/Y');
$next_sunday = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("next Sunday"));
$the_saturday_after_next_sunday = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("next Saturday", $next_sunday));

echo "today is: " . $today . "<br>";
echo "next sunday is: " . $next_sunday . "<br>";
echo "the saturday after next sunday is: " . $the_saturday_after_next_sunday . "<br>";
?>
```

I've also tried

```
$the_saturday_after_next_sunday = strtotime("next Saturday", $next_sunday);
```

Comment: [it just works here](http://codepad.org/Kcv3Vpfj), you _did_ remember to set your timezone properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sunday   = strtotime("next Sunday");
$saturday = $sunday + 60 * 60 * 24 * 6;
echo date('m/d/Y', $saturday);
```

This works since PHP 4.4, see http://3v4l.org/SUnaR

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
strtotime("next Saturday", strtotime($next_sunday))
```

Instead of:

```
strtotime("next Saturday", $next_sunday)
```

Comment: What you you think `strtotime(strtotime("next sunday"))` (what this essentially is) does?